# how to get multiple stock quote with symbol in python

Tags: python, stockquotes, alpha-vantage

I want to get NSE stocks only.
I m using to get multiple stocks quotes with a symbol in python.

code:

```
from nsetools import Nse

nse = Nse()

def get_current(stock):
    return nse.get_quote(stock)

for i in stocks:
        data = get_current(i)
```

This doesn't help.
please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fetch a list of quotes. Something like this perhaps:

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()
stocks = ['INDUSINDBK', 'SHREECEM']
data = [nse.get_quote(stock) for stock in stocks]
```

**Edit:** to just get last price per symbol, you can do:

```
symbol2price = {stock:nse.get_quote(stock)['lastPrice'] for stock in stocks}
```

which would then contain the symbols mapping to the last price, like so:

```
>>> symbol2price
{'INDUSINDBK': 510.25, 'SHREECEM': 21598.0}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick response. `data = [nse.get_quote(stock) for stock in nifty50]` with this I m getting an extra pile of data such as buy price,pre-close..etc but I only need symbol and current price. how to chop off extra fields. please help.

Comment: what is `symbol`? `{symbol:nse.get_quote(stock)['lastPrice'] for stock in stocks}` in this line

Comment: Sorry, used the wrong term, stock was what you called it.

Comment: @JonasByström If  `len(stocks)` is huge, fetching all the quotes would lead to the user's ip ban for making too many http requests, right ?

Comment: @aapa3e8 In all probability yes. Why? ;)

Comment: it is still making individual requests